# Book and Cookbook Links are not working in Symfony

Tags: symfony

yesterday, 2016-07-30, and today, 2016-07-31, the next links to access  the book and the cookbook for learning Symfony arent work:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html

Before these dates worked fine.

What's going on?

Thanks,
Mikel

Comment: http://symfony.com/blog/introducing-the-new-symfony-documentation

Comment: The exact [same kind of post yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662874/what-happened-to-the-symfony-cookbook). You should have check for similar questions first. -1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they change the layout and organisation of the site. You could see it on web :

- [former book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) in the getting started section
- [former cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/index.html)

you could also download them as pdf:

- [former book](http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_book_3.1.pdf)
- [former cookbook](http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_components_3.1.pdf)